# Where to configure grails.assets.excludes for Grails assets pipeline?

Tags: grails, asset-pipeline

Where should I configure grails.assets.excludes for Grails assets pipeline?

According to http://bertramdev.github.io/asset-pipeline/guide/configuration.html, you can include or exclude files for Asset Pipeline.

However, it doesn't specify where to add it. e.g. Do we put it in Config.groovy?

I never seem to get it working with the code below:

**index.gsp**:

```
<asset:stylesheet src="application.css" />
```

**application.css**:

```
*= require_tree ../stylesheets
```

**testing.css** (located under assets/stylesheets/testing.css):

```
body { background: green; }
```

**Config.groovy** (I assume this is the place to add the config):

```
grails.assets.excludes = ["**/testing.css"]
```

Everything else works apart from one issue: It never excludes testing.css.

Has anybody actually get it working? I have tried adding the config to BuildConfig.groovy and it doesn't work either.

Versions in use:

- Grails 2.4.2
- compile ":asset-pipeline:1.8.11"

Answer (score 2):

For grails 3.1, it goes in your build.gradle file:

```
assets {
    minifyJs = true
    minifyCss = true
    excludes = ["**/*.html"]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Where should I configure grails.assets.excludes for Grails assets
>   pipeline?

You are correct that it should go into config.groovy.

I tried the following and it worked (to exclude css from the routing plugin):

```
grails.assets.plugin."routing".excludes =["**/*.css"]
```

Try upgrading to a newer version of asset-pipeline (version 1.9.6 is the latest)

Comment: Hello mate. Thanks for the reply. I can't get it working. 1) I wouldn't be able to exclude css files within the current project, 2) I wouldn't be able to find a plugin with css for me to exclude, 3) The routing plugin you use have css under web-app/css, which would not be imported by asset-pipeline by default if I understand it correctly, so the files are excluded regardless if it have your line of code or not, 4) I have upgraded my asset-pipeline version and I still have the same issue.

Comment: Hi, I included the example exclude because that worked for my project. I tried to exclude on one file and I could not.
Instead of using "require_tree ../stylesheets", can you try to reference the files that you are using individually?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to exclude files from the precompiler phase to reduce excessive compiling.

1. You can use a combination of both excludes and includes patterns to restrict the files you need to process in `config.groovy`.

   **Example**
   You have a javascript file that requires `jquery.js`, you do not need to compile jQuery because when the javascript file is processed jQuery will get bundled together with it.

   ```
   grails.assets.excludes = ["jquery.js"]
   grails.assets.includes = ["application.js"]
   ```
2. Prefix files you do not want to precompile with an underscore ( _ )

   **Example**

   Original file name to be compiled individually: `example.js`

   New file name to be excluded: `_example.js`

[source](http://davydotcom.com/blog/2014-02-25-faster-asset-compilation-with-grails-asset-pipeline)